# como iniciar y detener jprogress bar con hilos en java

Tags: java

`introducir el código aquí`Lo que necesito que cuendo inice el jprogress se con un boton y si le vuelvo iniciar con otro boton se restablesca la barra donde se quedo anteriormente

`Thread hilo= new Thread(){ @Override public void run(){ for(int i=1; i<100; i++) try{ sleep(10); j2.setValue(i); }catch(InterruptedException ex){ Logger.getLogger(Formulario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex); } } }; hilo.start();`

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).